# iPhone development - Which is better for my app (Navigation or window based)?

Tags: iphone, view, navigation

It's a really simple question , but i'm still new at this.
I want to create a game with some levels.

Is it better to use a Navigation based app or a windows based?

views used are:(Main menu- Options - high scores - 10 levels)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a game, take a look at the [cocos2d framework](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/). It will provide a complete solution for this kind of programs.

As to your question, I would not use a Navigation base app, since you do not want to give the option of going back through levels. You just need a way to manage all the different scenes youd have (levels), moving from one to another, and display a menu/options view when it is the case. So, if you do not want to use cocos2d, a window based app will suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned cocos2d and started creating a whole new level of apps !

Answer (score 1):

Most games have a 100% custom UI, but if you are just getting started, you might want to prototype your screens/flow between screens using UIKit first.